Why would the US Senate introduce a bill as an amendment in the nature of a substitute to an unrelated bill?
For example, while the press hasn't covered this much, KOSA (the infamous Kids Online Safety Act) is now "KOSPA" after being combined with two other bills. However, this combination was done in a seemingly unorthodox way: as an amendment in the nature of a substitute to a bill originally on cutting down excess reports, S.2073. Now, S.2073 has the text of the KOSPA but the outdated summary on the excess report bill, which was debated, passed, and sent from the house for all reports-trimming purposes. So, why did the Commerce, Science, and Transportation US Senate committee decide to introduce this bill in this manner? What happens to the original S. 2073? Is there precedent for this?

This sort of thing happens all the time for reasons from getting the amendment passed as part of a must pass bill, or to kill a bill that would otherwise pass, or for many other various reasons.

Could you add some precedents and form an answer? Since the original excess-reports bill passed the senate before being sent to the house and back, I doubt that they wanted to kill it.

This is something that happens all the time, adding an amendment to kill a bill was only one of the options. I also said it was done to pass an amendment on a must pass bill or for other reasons. As I said there are many different reasons that this is done in congress so it is hard to say why in this case.

Please spell out all acronyms at least once in a question.

As @JoeW mentioned, this happens All. The. Time. On occasion, congress critters have tried to pass a new rule that requires a bill to be about one topic, or that amendments to a bill to be somehow related to the original bill, but those proposed rule changes inevitably fail. Amendments are just too useful of a tool for both houses of congress, and for both sides of the aisle, to just give them up.

This question would be more interesting to most of us - who don't know what KOSPA is about - if it went into some more details of the context.  From the comments almost get the sense some of the additions are antethical to the main body - which would certainly be interesting.  But not going to follow a link - which might very well be a dead link 2 years from now, making this question really hard to follow.  Welcome aboard, and +1 for an imperfectly-asked but apparently intriguing question.

Thanks @ItalianPhilosopher! I meant for the question to be a bit more general, so I've changed the question title.

If you search for the introductory phrase "In lieu of the matter proposed to be inserted, insert the following" there are plenty of hits to other instances. Going back at least to 1878 if you also use/include Google Books.
In Congress jargon, this is known as "an amendment in the nature of a substitute" aka "complete substitute".

There are several different types of amendments. A first-degree amendment proposes to change
the text of the bill; a second-degree amendment proposes to change the text of a first-degree
amendment that the Senate is considering. Third-degree amendments are not allowed. An
amendment may propose to strike out language from a bill (or a first-degree amendment), insert
new language, or replace language by striking out and inserting. In general, an amendment that
proposes to replace the entire text of a bill is known as an amendment in the nature of a
substitute; an amendment to replace the entire text of a first-degree amendment is known as a
substitute amendment. An amendment, especially in the second degree, that makes some lesser
change is known as a perfecting amendment.
[...] A complete substitute (denoted in this report as an
amendment in the nature of a substitute) is a special form of substitute amendment that proposes
to replace the entire text of the measure—to strike all after the enacting clause and insert “in lieu
thereof” a different text.
Unlike the House, the Senate does not use the phrase “amendment in the nature of a substitute” to refer consistently
and exclusively to an amendment that proposes to strike out all after the enacting clause of a bill (or resolving clause of
a resolution) and replace that text with a different text. For purposes of clarity, the phrase will be used only in that sense
in this report, but it should be borne in mind that Senators may use the same phrase in a broader sense. When an
amendment in the nature of a substitute has been offered, it is not considered to be a first-degree amendment; thus, the
amendment in the nature of a substitute is open to two degrees of amendment.

Anyhow, according to Wikipedia, citing another CRS report

In the United States Congress, substitute amendments are often used to replace the text of a bill that is no longer being considered with the text of an unrelated bill. In this case, it is said that the former bill is being used as a legislative vehicle for the latter. This has the effect of skipping steps of the legislative process, such as the need for a bill to be passed by a Congressional committee. This is possible because there is no general requirement that amendments offered by senators on the floor must be germane or relevant to the bill being considered.

My guess is (thus) that since KOSA and possibly the other bits it was combined with already went through some Senate committees in their previous incarnation that it was deemed unnecessary to do so again. Especially since it passed the Senate with some 90 votes in favor AFAICT.
The reason for these maneuvers appears to be that the House of Representatives particularly its Speaker refused (or did not commit) to consider it, neither in previous or in its current incarnation. Whether the Senate hoped that by combining it with other bits would make it more palatable to the House (Speaker), I've not been able to determine yet.

The House has not yet acted on the bill. Speaker Mike Johnson, R-La., has said he is “committed to working to find consensus,” but has not said whether he will bring it to the floor for a vote. Supporters are hoping that the strong Senate vote will push the House to act before the end of the congressional session in January.

FWTW, there are some further amendments proposed in the House. These are also in the form of
"an amendment in the nature of a substitute" but to H.R. 7891.

Q: What happen[ed] to the original S. 2073?
The actions on S.2073 show that the original text (6/21/2023) was replaced by committee "in the nature of a substitute" (7/26/2023) before being passed by the Senate. The bill went to the House where it was amended and passed (5/06/2024) before being returned to the Senate.
The amended text approved by the House is contained in TITLE III—ELIMINATING USELESS REPORTS of S.2073.

Yeah, I understand that. With that part of the question, I’m asking what’s the next steps for the original text of the bill.

The next step depends on the House. If the House approves, the bill with its amended text of the original S.2073 is sent to the president along with the KOSPA amendments. If the House does nothing, the bill expires and the Eliminate Useless Reports Act can be brought up again in the next Congress. If the House amends the bill, it is returned to the Senate.

Is there a rule preventing the original text from reintroduction within this congress?

No. The House could remove the Senate amendment and return the bill or remove the text to a House bill, approve it again, and send it to the Senate. Either of those actions would signal that the House does not intend to consider Kids Online Safety or Teen Privacy in the current Congress.

And they could also just reintroduce the old bill while still considering KOSPA?
